# is this correct syntax in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

In the jquery below should there be a closing paretheses ")" before the "dot" in:

"`.test($` ..."?

`(/^\s*$/.test($(this).val()))`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#userlogin').css('color', '#cccccc').val('LOGINNAME');   

    $('#userlogin').blur(function () {
        if (/^\s*$/.test($(this).val())) {
            $(this).val('LOGINNAME');
            $(this).css('color', '#cccccc');
            $(this).valid();
        }
    }).focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === 'LOGINNAME') {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).css('color', '#000000');
        }
    });
```

If not, why not? That code looks a little weird to me.

Comment: ``/something/`` is a regular expression. In Javascript they are objects with methods, and ``test`` is one such method. There's nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: There is one more way to avoid confusion like this and that is proper code formatting with some whitespace to render the code les cryptic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is correct:

```
/^\s*$/  // create a regex
  .test( // call the test method on it
    $(this) // create a jquery object
      .val() // call the val method on it
  )
```

However, the value could be cached: `var val = $(this).val();`.
Then the line might be less confusing to you: `/yourregex/.test(val)`

Comment: It matches a string that is empty or consists of nothing but whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

`/^\s*$/` is a regular expression literal and it has a test method which is being called. The brackets are from the if condition which is bigger.

Since javascript is fully object oriented even literals can have methods.

Comment: +1. if I could select more than one answer, I would.  Thanks for explaining that regular expressions are literals and have methods. That really helped.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^\s*$/.test( $(this).val() )
```

The first part is a regular expression - not a string or anything else. As such, it begins and ends with deliminters `/` and `/`.

Using `.match` is sometimes more legible as it doesn't appear to have some strange unbound item floating around in the source:

```
$(this).val().match(/^\s*$/);
```

This particular expression, broken down, reads like this:

```
/^   // Beginning of String
\s*  // Space, zero or more times
$/   // End of String
```

So it will test positive if there are zero or more spaces, from start to finish, and nothing else.

Comment: *There actually shouldn't be a paren at the beginning* - he copied from his `if()` statement

Comment: @JonathanSampson, +1 this helps me as well to understand.  I found this link on google https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @Chris22 The Mozilla Developer network is always helpful. I also noted that you had asked what this expression meant, so I've updated my answer to contain that explanation as well.

Answer (score 2):

The code is fine. If you think its unreadable why not create the regex first

```
var regex = /^\s*$/;
if(regex.test($(this).val())
    ...
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you pass a string when using `new RegExp()`. However, don't do this unless you have to. Using a string means you have to double-escape backslashes etc.

Comment: Oh right. It's a while since I've done regexs in JS. Thanks for the input

Comment: @Ash, yes if it were coded like that, I would have understood it a ilttle better.  I didn't know reg expressions could have methods